# How to reboot another Mac via Terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, reboot

Recently my main computer freezes up more often, and instead of giving him the hard treatment by pushing the power button, I'd rather reboot him gently.

So I grab my laptop, fire up Terminal and login to my main computer.

```
ssh username@ip-address
```

I enter my password and that’s how far I come every time. I know that I can *kill single processes*, but when I try the **reboot** or **restart** command, my laptop reboots, *not* the main computer which I logged into via `ssh`.

I think it is possible, so this goes out to the advanced terminal user (I'm a beginner).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Once you've logged in via ssh then you need to use `shutdown` with the `-r` flag (for restart):

```
$ ssh username@ip-address
$ sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Or, to do it all in one command:

```
$ ssh username@ip-address sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Comment: you can also type it all in one line "ssh user@host sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now"

Comment: Thank you guys - works flawless and saves me some time. Luckily my computer hasn't had any freezes lately.